# How can i count same text cell values count for multiple values in excel sheet

Tags: excel, count

How can i count same multiple values in a row.[image]

Comment: pls see my question once again, i am updated, i have only one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference:

[image]

Comment: @Rathinam - `COUNTIF` formula counts the number of cells in the range specified that meets a criteria. For example if you'll see formula in `Row 3` it is `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A3,A3)` that means the range is `A1:A3` and criteria is to match value in `Cell A3` which is `A`. So from `A1:A3` count of `A` is 3.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is With an ARRAY-formula, assuming the letters are in column B.

Put this in `C2`
`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B19=B2,MATCH(B2:B19,B2:B19,0)),ROW(B2:B19)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))`finsh the formula With pushing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` This will show you how many letter in a descending matter.

[image: First_Array]

If you just need the total you can use this in `C2` `=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$19=B2,MATCH($B$2:$B$19,$B$2:$B$19,0)),ROW($B$2:$B$19)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))`finsh the formula With pushing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

[image: Second_Array]

Or you can modify this to put the letter you are searching for in a cell and this formula next to it and find the instances for it.
Eg. search/cell is `D1` then the fomula looks like this in `E1`

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$19=D1,MATCH(B2:B19,B2:B19,0)),ROW(B2:B19)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))`finsh the formula with pushing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: for this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/aobcq.jpg  how can i get count start with 1,

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is an iterative counter - provided your list is sorted

```
if this row data equals last row data then
    this row counter = last row counter + 1
else
    this row counter = 1
end if
```

I put the formula doing this as clear text into [D3]

the second simplest solution might be a Pivot table ... your data doesn't have to be sorted, and you don't spoil your data table with an extra counter column

Note that the Pivot Data range is only `B2:B19`, column C isn't needed here

[image]

Comment: pls once again see my question, i had only data column, not count column

Comment: i have only data no count, i need count like my question screen shot

Comment: the formula in column C (with cleartext in D3) provides exactly this